# How to get value of the attribute of the xml file using java

Tags: java, xml

I am getting following code in response in xml

```
<.........>
   <stsuuser:Attribute name="authorized" type="urn:ibm:names:ITFIM:oauth:response:decision">
         <stsuuser:Value>TRUE</stsuuser:Value>
   </stsuuser:Attribute>   
<.........>
```

Now how I can get `<stsuuser:Value>` is true or false using Java?

Comment: Google: XML parser Java

Comment: have a look at an XML parser. If you have a more specific question later ask again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Reading XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704827/java-reading-xml-file)

Comment: Here I have issue because prefix with element name is exist and i am new for this so.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite literally dozens of libraries for Java that parse XML. But, I find [JOOX](https://code.google.com/p/joox/) by far the simplest to use. It lacks quite a few common features of other libraries, but unlike them, it's a joy to use. It provides you with a jQuery-like API (even has the $ function) and, in your case, you'd use it as follows:

```
import static org.joox.JOOX.$;
...
//Get the value of "authorized" attribute
$(...).xpath("//Attribute[@name='authorized']/Value").text();
```

The $ function will accepts a String, a file, a stream, a reader etc, so you can initialize with pretty much anything.