# Issue while reading xml contents

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xquery

I need a little help in one of the scenario I have.
I have this XMl

```
<catalogOfferID>
   <catalogOfferID>5609805</catalogOfferID>
</catalogOfferID>
```

I wanted to fetch 5609805 from this as catalogOfferID.

The logic I am using

But the problem is as due to the same name of parent and child tag it is giving me result like `<catalogOfferID>5609805`

Please help me in solving this problem.

TIA.

Comment: Where is the logic you are using? To me, the result looks legit, apart from the need to cast that string to an integer

Comment: @NicoHaase The result seems to be together with the `<catalogOfferID>`, which was not shown due to missing formatting... Found this via *edit*. But the *logic I am using* is not there at all...

Answer (score 2):

A quick shot is to use an `XPath` like this:

```
//catalogOfferID/catalogOfferID/text()
```

or

```
//catalogOfferID[text()]/text()
```

But what you show is not enough for a serious answer...

### UPDATE

After reading your question in edit-mode I found, that you get the result as

> `<catalogOfferID>`5609805

This shows quite clearly, that you are trying to get this on string level between `<catalogOfferID>` and `</catalogOfferID>`. You should **never!!** read XML this way. Use the appropriate XML classes! Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7704827/5089204) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2811001/5089204) for a start.