# How to validate xml with dtd using java?

Tags: java, xml, dtd

I have following xml file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
<Employee>
    <Emp_Id>E-001</Emp_Id>
    <Emp_Name>Vinod</Emp_Name>
    <Emp_E-mail>Vinod1@yahoo.com</Emp_E-mail>
</Employee>
```

I have following dtd file:

```
<!ELEMENT Employee (Emp_Id, Emp_Name, Emp_E-mail)>
<!ELEMENT Emp_Id (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Emp_Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Emp_E-mail (#PCDATA)>
```

I want to validate this xml file with above dtd using java.

Please, help thanks..:-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are three things you should do:

- Associate the source XML document with its DTD using a doctype declaration *after* the XML declaration:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE Employee SYSTEM "employee.dtd">
  ```

  **Note**: The DOCTYPE root must match the root element in the source XML.
- `setValidating` to `true` on the `DocumentBuilderFactory`
- Provide an `org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler` instance to the `DocumentBuilder` using `setErrorHandler`

Here's a complete example:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setValidating(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
builder.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        // do something more useful in each of these handlers
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
});
Document doc = builder.parse("employee.xml");
```

Source document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Employee SYSTEM "employee.dtd">
<Employee>
    <Emp_Id> E-001</Emp_Id>
    <Emp_Name> Vinod </Emp_Name>
    <Emp_E-mail> Vinod1@yahoo.com </Emp_E-mail>
</Employee>
```

Comment: Thanks lwburk!! but I dont allow to change in original source xml file.

Comment: @SachinJ - read the file into memory, insert the DOCTYPE line, have the builder parse the XML string instead of a disk file.

Comment: Sorry for the question but... where should I set the DTD filepath of the file set as "SYSTEM"?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to read the files and report the exceptions, if any. Here is a [SAX parser example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373567/java-how-to-read-and-write-xml-files/7373596#7373596) you can rely upon.

In order to validate your XML and DTD you just need to setValidating:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setValidating(true); // since the default value is false
```

Also declare the DTD usage in your XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Employee SYSTEM "employee.dtd">
<Employee>
```

Comment: *Document root element "Employee", must match DOCTYPE root "employee".*