# Valid XML and DTD not validating

Tags: java, xml, validation

I am trying to validate the following xml against the following DTD using the following Java code. (JDK 8 - All files are correctly found in the classpath). It is throwing the following exceptions.

Everything seems to be correct, and the IDE is not showing any red underlines when I embed the dtd in the xml, so I assume all syntax is correct. The error message says the exception is line number 1. When I add a blank line to the top of the DTD it changes that to line number 2, so I am pretty sure it is not liking the DTD. I tried the same using examples downloaded over the internet, and get the same issue.

What am I doing wrong???

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
    <property>key1=value1</property>
</properties>
```

test.dtd:

```
<!ELEMENT properties (property)*>
   <!ELEMENT property (#PCDATA)>
```

Validate.java:

```
public static void validateXml(String xmlFile, String dtdFile) 
    throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, URISyntaxException
{
    URL dtdUrl = XmlUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResource(dtdFile);
    System.out.println("DTD:\n" + new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(dtdUrl.toURI()))));

    // parse an XML document into a DOM tree
    DocumentBuilder parser = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    URL xmlUrl = XmlUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResource(xmlFile);
    System.out.println("XML:\n" + new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(xmlUrl.toURI()))));

    Document document = parser.parse(xmlUrl.openStream());

    // create a SchemaFactory capable of understanding WXS schemas
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

    // load a WXS schema, represented by a Schema instance
    Reader dtdReader = new URLReader(dtdUrl);
    Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(dtdReader);

    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
    // create a Validator instance, which can be used to validate an instance document
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

    // validate the DOM tree
    validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
}
```

System.out:

```
DTD:
<!ELEMENT properties (property)*>
        <!ELEMENT property (#PCDATA)>
XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
    <property>key1=value1</property>
</properties>
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 3;
The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper
    .createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use your DTD as if it were an [XML Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema) (XSD).  It's not an XML Schema, it's a DTD.

An XML Schema is itself an XML document.  The error arises because your DTD cannot be parsed as an XML document and hence neither as an XML Schema.

See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699620/how-to-validate-xml-with-dtd-using-java) for how to validate your XML document against a DTD.