# Rhino 'document' is not defined

Tags: javascript, rhino

I am trying to use Rhino to covert some JavaScript code to Java. As anyone who has any experience at all with JavaScript knows "document" is used for lots of things. So, it is used in various functions in the code I am using. However, when I execute Rhino it just gives me this error 
`js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined.`

Does anyone know what is causing this? And if so how to fix it? I am using Rhino version 1.7 on Ubuntu 14.10 64 bit.

Or if anyone could atleast show me how to evaluate JavaScript from within Java. I have done some research, but the code never works.

Comment: What is the nature of the JavaScript code you're trying to "convert"?

Comment: Outside a browser based environment `document` doesn't mean much

Comment: Well then, what would I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of digging and research I have been able to find out how to resolve this problem...

#### I have done two things.

I stopped using Rhino (considering it is outdated) and I switched to Nashorn

---

I also found out how to implement document

[How to append xml nodes (as a string) into an existing XML Element node (only using java builtins)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108726/how-to-append-xml-nodes-as-a-string-into-an-existing-xml-element-node-only-us)

That took very unconventional means to find this answer, which would make any programmer go "Oh...That's one way to do it."

The way implemented in the question actually worked.

## DISCLAIMER

My problems are not completely solved. Nashorn still gives me this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.String to org.w3c.dom.DocumentType` But, that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

Rhino is a just interpreter with only defines base object. Object such as 'document' 'window' is external HTML DOM object. It is out of scope for Rhino, or any other Javascript interpreter (such as jscript(IE) , V8 , spidermonkey, and nashorn).

Please refer java-based HtmlUnit which also uses Rhino and it defines most of HTML DOM objects. It is updated quite well.

Comment: So, how could I get around this?

Comment: Since HtmlUnit can't just load JavaScript code and spit out Java code in a specified file name.

Comment: okay. you have second question. You like to convert js to java class? Please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231550/has-anyone-used-or-written-an-ant-task-to-compile-rhino-javascript-to-java-byt/3567406#3567406

Comment: I hope it helps. I have never used this feature. Good luck!

Comment: This still doesn't help.

Comment: I'm very sorry! Nashorn may be better.