# BufferedWriter to write at BufferedReader position

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

My code reads through an xml file encoded with UTF-8 until a specfied string has been found. It finds the specified string fine, but I wish to write at this point in the file.

I would much prefer to do this through a stream as only small tasks need to be done.

I cannot find a way to do this. Any alternative methods are welcome.

Code so far:

```
final String RESOURCE = "/path/to/file.xml";

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(RESOURCE), "UTF-8"));
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(ClassLoader.class.getResource(RESOURCE).getPath()),"UTF-8"));

String fileLine = in.readLine();

while (!fileLine.contains("some string")) {

    fileLine = in.readLine();

}

// File writing code here
```

Comment: Better you use `XML Parser` for this operations see [--> Java: How to read and write xml files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373567/java-how-to-read-and-write-xml-files) **AND** [--> XML Parsing for Java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really write into the middle of the file, except for overwriting existing bytes (using something like `RandomAccessFile`).  that would only work, however, if what you needed to write was *exactly* the same byte length as what you were replacing, which i highly doubt.

instead, you need to re-write the file to a new file, copying the input to the output, replacing the parts you need to replace in the process.  there are a variety of ways you could do this.  i would recommend using a StAX event reader and writer as the StAX api is fairly user friendly (compared to SAX) as well as fast and memory efficient.