# How to get text from specific tag in XML using Java?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, text

I have an xml which web resource and I have String to URL where the xml is and in it I have to find specific tag **someTag** and to get its text content. How to do it in java?

I search but only find ways where there is specific XPath,but in my case I do not know where **someTag** can be. Which parser to use? And how to implement it?

Comment: If you know XML, you can create JAXB object and unmarshal xml into object. This way it will be more easy.

Comment: Looks like this question has already been asked : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373567/java-how-to-read-and-write-xml-files. Also see [http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/]

Comment: XPath is a part of the standard Java library.  It can parse XML.

Comment: A tag name by itself can be an XPath. You don't need to know where it is.

Answer (score 2):

An XPath expression starting with a double slash will find an element anywhere:

```
 XPathExpression xpw = xpath.compile( "//someTag" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently used transformer class to process stix xml messages.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html