# How to get XHTML file to object in java and how to work with it?

Tags: java, html, xml

I got XHTML file **.hocr** from tesseract 3.03 on Ubuntu 14.04LTS. How can I put data from this file to an object in java? Or how else I can work with this? Unfortunatelly for me, Im unexperienced with working with XML files, so any help would be much appreciated.

example of file:

```
<div class='ocr_page' id='page_1' title='image "test2jpg.jpg"; bbox 0 0 10000 10000; ppageno 0'>
  <div class='ocr_carea' id='block_1_1' title="bbox 250 192 8637 686">
    <p class='ocr_par' dir='ltr' id='par_1_1' title="bbox 250 192 8637 686">
      <span class='ocr_line' id='line_1_1' title="bbox 250 192 8637 414; baseline 0 -40">
        <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_1' title='bbox 250 192 1606 375; x_wconf 70' lang='eng' dir='ltr'>NAME</span>
        <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_2' title='bbox 1676 192 3051 375; x_wconf 73' lang='eng' dir='ltr'><strong>FIRSTNAME</strong></span>
```

Unique identificator should be "**word_1_X**" where the **X** stands for number.

Point is to get NAME and FIRSTNAME and their possitions in picture.
For example:

> word_1_1 has X1=250 Y1=192
>
> X2=1606 Y2=375

string value NAME.

Any ideas how to simply achieve this?

Comment: Apart from the question which I have difficulties to understand in, use an appropriate XML parser which you are interested in like JAXB (included as part of the Java SE 6 API) or JAXP. There is also an HTML parser JSOUP, if you need it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to read and write xml files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373567/java-how-to-read-and-write-xml-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally use a XML parser to parse XML files.

But as it appears to be actually a HTML file (most likely just the HTML output produced by a XHTML file as part of a JSF web application), then you'd better use a HTML parser.

There are [many HTML parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers), one of them most suitable for the task of parsing real world HTML files and extracting specific data would be [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org).

Provided that the HTML output is available on the URL `http://example.com/some/page.jsf`, here's how you could use Jsoup to extract the data of interest:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/some/page.jsf").get();

for (Element ocrxWord : document.select(".ocrx_word")) {
    String text = ocrxWord.text(); // NAME, FIRSTNAME, etc
    String title = ocrxWord.attr("title"); // bbox 250 192 1606 375; x_wconf 70, etc
    // ...
}
```

After having the title, it would be just a matter of using basic `java.lang.String` methods to breakdown it further in smaller parts. That responsibility is beyond the scope of the HTML parser, any Java beginner is able to figure it on their own.

Comment: Yea, thank you for your help, havent done anything like this yet so Im a bit clueless here + language barriere. I will try it out later today and mark as solved if it will work.