# DocumentBuilder doc (with root element) outputs null even though root element is appended

Tags: java, xml, dom, javax.xml

I'm attempting to have it return my empty root element with attributes but am getting [#document: null] output.  Am I absolutely required to have a child element for the root?

```
String docDate = "1";
String docNumber = "1";
String orderType = "1";
String transactionType = "1";

try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("InvoiceRequest");

    Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("documentDate");
    attr.setValue(docDate);
    rootElement.setAttributeNode(attr);

    Attr attr2 = doc.createAttribute("documentNumber");
    attr2.setValue(docNumber);
    rootElement.setAttributeNode(attr2);

    Attr attr3 = doc.createAttribute("orderType");
    attr3.setValue(orderType);
    rootElement.setAttributeNode(attr3);

    Attr attr4 = doc.createAttribute("transactionType");
    attr4.setValue(transactionType);
    rootElement.setAttributeNode(attr4);

    doc.appendChild(rootElement);
    System.out.println("doc: " + doc.toString());
} catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DocumentImpl` is a subclass of `NodeImpl`, whose `toString()` implementation reads:

```
public String toString() {
    return "["+getNodeName()+": "+getNodeValue()+"]";
}
```

`getNodeName()` returns `#document` (which makes sense) - this is defined in `CoreDocumentImpl`. `getNodeValue()` returns `null` because it is not overridden. This behaviour is even mentioned in the [`Node`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) documentation:

> In cases where there is no obvious mapping of these attributes for a specific nodeType (e.g., nodeValue for an Element or attributes for a Comment ), this returns null.

Because your root element is not included in either `getNodeName()` or `getNodeValue()`, it might look empty. But there's nothing to worry about. You need [other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373567/java-how-to-read-and-write-xml-files) to render the document as an XML string.

Comment: You may add the Javadoc comment of the [`Node`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) interface which clearly explains that elements do not have a node value.

Comment: You're welcome. I was already on the way for an own answer. But you came first. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `toString()` method which you are using here is doing nothing but just returning:-

`"["+getNodeName()+": "+getNodeValue()+"]"`

so correspondingly you are getting :-

```
[#document: null] //nodeName as document and null nodevalue
```

Don't worry about it & keep on doing your further processing, you will get your intended result and not an `NPE`.