# How to get extension property on camunda process engine using java

Tags: java, camunda, camunda-modeler

I have several processes in my camunda process model. I want to sort them after a numerical order, therefore I added a variable in each process which I called "process_order" and giving them a number which represents the order (1 is the first priority, 2 is second priority etc.) as shown in the picture below.

[image: process_order in extension property on the whole process]

In the BPMN file it looks like this:

[image: bpmn file]

So I'm wondering how to get the extension property out using Java?

Thanks for any reply :)

Comment: [How to read and write xml files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373567/how-to-read-and-write-xml-files)

Comment: Refer :https://forum.camunda.org/t/how-do-i-read-model-camunda-property-in-a-java-delegate-execution-listener/6080

Answer (score 2):

When / from where would you like to read the property?

Does the model API doc here answer your question?
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/model-api/bpmn-model-api/extension-elements/

If you need to read the information from an execution:

```
ServiceTask serviceTask = (ServiceTask) execution.getBpmnModelElementInstance();

CamundaProperties camProperties = serviceTask.getExtensionElements().getElementsQuery().filterByType(CamundaProperties.class).singleResult(); 

    for (CamundaProperty camProperty : camProperties.getCamundaProperties()) 
        {
          String name = camProperty.getCamundaName();
          String value = camProperty.getCamundaValue();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a java class as a listener as shown in below image.

Java class should implement the org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate.

In the overriden method,you can get the variable by

execution.getVariable("variable-name")

[Camunda Process Listener Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feW7s.png)

Comment: I don´t think it works like you are saying. I´´ve try it and it´s not getting it.