# How to generate xml in Java?

Tags: java, xml, sax

Please, tell me, how to generate XML in Java?
I couldn't find any example using SAX framework.

Comment: What do you need? Read an xml file from java or generate an xml file from java?

Comment: Generate an xml file from java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating XML using SAX and Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898590/generating-xml-using-sax-and-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_XML_21days&seqNum=221), [this](http://www.javazoom.net/services/newsletter/xmlgeneration.html), [Generating XML using SAX and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898590/generating-xml-using-sax-and-java) and [this](http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2007/06/xml-generation-in-java.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try [Xembly](https://github.com/yegor256/xembly), a small open source library that wraps native Java DOM with a "fluent" interface:

```
String xml = new Xembler(
  new Directives()
    .add("root")
    .add("order")
    .attr("id", "553")
    .set("$140.00")
).xml();
```

Will generate:

```
<root>
  <order id="553">$140.00</order>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Although this is not a built-in library, interesting advice.

Answer (score 1):

SAX is a library to parse existing XML files with Java. It is not to create a new XML file out of Java. If you want to do this use a library like DOM4J to create a XML tree and then write it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use libraries like [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbay.html) or [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) or [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) if you want to easily map/convert your java objects to XML.

Say we have a simple entity/pojo - Item.The properties of the pojo class can be made the XML's element or attribute with simple annotations.

```
@Entity @Root public class Item {

@Attribute
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Transient
@ManyToOne
private Order order;

@Element
private String product;

@Element
private double price;

@Element
private int quantity; }
```

To generate XML from this item, the code can be simply

```
Serializer serializer=new Persister();//SimpleXML serializer
    Item itemToSerializeToXml=new Item(2456L, "Head First Java", 250.00,10);//Object to be serialized
    StringWriter destinationXMLWriter=new StringWriter();//Destination of XML
    serializer.write(itemToSerializeToXml,destinationXMLWriter);//Call to serialize the POJO to XML
    System.out.println(destinationXMLWriter.toString());
```

Comment: Above code generated XML: `<item id="2456">
   <product>Head First Java</product>
   <price>250.0</price>
   <quantity>10</quantity>
</item>`

Comment: Doesn't compile, since none of the annotations is defined.

Answer (score 1):

use dom4j, here is quick start for **dom4j**

[dom4j guide](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice library for XML creation on GitHub at https://github.com/jmurty/java-xmlbuilder . Really good for simple documents at least (I didn't have an opportunity to employ it for anything bigger than around a dozen lines).

The good thing about this library is that each of its commands (i.e. create attribute, create element, etc.) has 3 levels of abbreviations. For example, to add the tag `<foo>` to the document you can use the following methods:

- `.e("foo")` (single-letter form)
- `.elem("foo"` (4 letter form)
- `.element("foo")` (fully spelled-out form)

This allows creating XML using both longer and more abbreviated code, as appropriate, so it can be a good fit for a variety of coding styles.