# How to create an XML document programmatically in Java?

Tags: java, xml, file-io, android-manifest, manifest

Given a pre-described set of tags which I can use(for example, a structure like the AndroidManifest.xml), how can I create an XML document (for a manifest file) from scratch in Java, preferably not using any third party libraries?

Also, what is(if any) the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373567/java-how-to-read-and-write-xml-files

Comment: There are several ways to read and write XML files. SAX, DOM, JAXB (all included in the JRE) and [many more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898590/generating-xml-using-sax-and-java) (there are some examples, especially using the [XML Stream Writer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4898623/1692341)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to generate XML without third party framework

1. SAX and DOM (powerful yet complex)
2. Jax-B (relatively easy)

The simplest way to generate an XML is to use Jax-B (which comes as a standard from JEE6 onwards).Refer [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) for more details on Jax-B

But if your trying to implement this in Android(since you mentioned AndroidManifest.xml) then I recommend you to use some third party framework like [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) to avoid unwanted complications, because it is more lightweight than the rest of the above mentioned technologies and easy to use.

If your strict on not using third party library(which I do not recommend), then use SaxParser in Android, refer [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334859/Parsing-XML-in-Android-with-SAX) for some examples.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
Overview of Java DOM API for XMLType
```

Oracle XML DB supports the Java Document Object Model (DOM) Application Program Interface (API) for XMLType. This is a generic API for client and server, for both XML schema-based and non-schema-based documents. It is implemented using the Java package oracle.xdb.dom. DOM is an in-memory tree-based object representation of XML documents that enables programmatic access to their elements and attributes. The DOM object and interface are part of a W3C recommendation. DOM views the parsed document as a tree of objects.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb11jav.htm

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/how-to-generate-an-xml-document-programmatically-using-system-xml-xmlwriter-part-iii/

Comment: This is C#, not Java.